# AWK Compare 2 columns in 2 files, print if one is equal while other is not

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to print all lines from File one + column 3 from File two if column one in both files matches but column 3 doesnt match.

Example:

```
File1  
John  12  Mango  
David  13  Apple  
Jack 14  Orange  

File2   
John  12  Grape  
David  13  Apple  
Jack 14  Apple
```

Output

```
John 12 Mango Grape  
Jack 14 Orange Apple
```

I tried different awk commands but they work when both column matches but I need to print when only 1 column match and other doesn't. I am fairly new to script and Unix command, I would appreciate little explanation of the proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3; next} ($1 in a) && (a[$1] != $3){print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
John 12 Mango Grape
Jack 14 Orange Apple
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, rest of the solutions work as well but this allows easier modification. Ed, would you be able to provide a breakdown of your syntax and/or suggest any tutorial for the same usage of AWK ?

Comment: creates an array mapping of $1 to $3 when reading file2, then if $1 from file1 is an index in that array it compares the $3 for the current $1 to the $3 saved in the array by that same index when it was read from file2. If the current $1 from file1 was a $1 in file2 and the $3 vale from file1 is not the same as the $3 value from fie 1 then it prints the current line from file1 followed by the $3 from file2 indexed by $1. Hope that makes sense. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold RObbins,

Comment: A quick question to @EdMorton, how will the syntax be if after the match, we want to print the entire line of file 2 instead?

Comment: @Jacek please post a new followup question.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[$1" "$2]=$3; next }
{ s=$1" "$2;
  if (s in a && a[s] != $3)
     printf("%s %s %s\n", s, a[s], $3)
}
```

Running:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input1.txt input2.txt
John 12 Mango Grape
Jack 14 Orange Apple
```

> EDIT generic version: match column 1 and mismatch in column col

```
$ cat tst2.awk
BEGIN {col=3}
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$0; next }
$1 in a {
   split(a[$1],b," ");
   if ($col!=b[col])
       print a[$1], $col
}
```

You could even delete the `BEGIN` from the awk file and add the variable col commandline, like this:

```
$ awk -v col=3 -f tst2.awk input1.txt input2.txt
John 12 Mango Grape
Jack 14 Orange Apple
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Marc. But is there a way that I could specifically match column one only and missmatch in column 3 ? regardless of 2nd column. The reason I asked is depending on the situation I might need to change the column for match and missmatch and in future I might have additional columns upto 6 total.

Comment: Added a more generic version to answer.

Answer (score 0):

**paste** + **awk** approach:

```
paste <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | awk '$1==$4 && $3!=$6{ print $1,$2,$3,$6 }'
```

The output:

```
Jack 14 Orange Apple
John 12 Mango Grape
```

Comment: Thats an interesting solution but i think it will be limited if the either file has extra lines and will cause an offset for the rest of the records.

Answer (score 0):

If you need generic solution, following a simple Perl script ( ~ 30 lines ), it should work for the arbitrary number of columns in files and matched/mismatched column numbers given as input parameters -

```
use strict;

my @f1; my @f2;

open F, config()->{file1} or die $!;
while (<F>){
  chomp;
  next unless /\S+/;
  push @f1, [ split /\s+/ ];
}
close F;

open F, config()->{file2} or die $!;
while (<F>){
  chomp;
  next unless /\S+/;
  push @f2, [ split /\s+/ ];
}
close F;

my $c1 = config()->{'match_col_num'}-1;
my $c2 = config()->{'mismatch_col_num'}-1;

for my $l1 (@f1){
  for my $l2 (@f2){
    if ($l1->[$c1] eq $l2->[$c1] and $l1->[$c2] ne $l2->[$c2]){
      print join " ", (@{$l1}, $l2->[$c2]);
      print "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

See usage info at https://github.com/melezhik/file-compare-columns